# Deployment of Silverlight RIA Services Application

Tags: .net, silverlight, deployment, wcf-ria-services

Testing on local Web Development Server and running the application in shared hosting environment differs a lot.

What are the best steps to deploy a Silverlight RIA Services Application on a shared hosting environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIA services assumes you are of course running ASP.Net hosting. You really want to be running an IIS7 server if you can (to allow dynamic URL mapping out-of-the-box as well).

If you have IIS 7 hosting it is almost 100% likely the server is already configured correctly to run Silverlight with RIA services. IIS 6 might need some updates installed first.

Unless you have your service as a separate site to your Silverlight deployment site 
RIA services will generally "just work" on your shared hosting. Just deploy a sample RIA site and see what happens. If you have specific issues post the details and go from there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you might need to look into is the web server serving .xap files. Your Silverlight application is compiled to become a .xap extension file and will your shared hosting web server allow that extension to be served by the server? I would check that out.